# Trouble with JPanels realizing the appropriate size

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, preferredsize

I have a project due in about an hour and I need to figure out the problem in my code before submitting.

In essence, there are two classes: one is a game and the other is a gui that should contain that game, some useless buttons, and a picture.

I'm having trouble making it all fit. I think I have a problem with the `JPanel`s. (There might be some useless looking methods, but I had plans for them and I'll see if I have enough time for them to come into fruition)

This is life and death for my grade. I'd be eternally grateful if you could fix this code for me.

I'm positive the problem is not in the nitty gritty of the second link. It's been tested on its own and works.

Here's the code

http://pastebay.net/1236108

http://pastebay.net/1236109

Here's what I get when I run the code:

[image]

Comment: What's it supposed to look like?

Comment: One of our problems is you are creating two different windows, adding a bunch to one and ignoring the other...Another is the use static variables that should be instance variables...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get rid of the `window` in the `Hangman` constructor.  `Hangman` is already frame.
2. Use `pack` instead of `setSize`
3. Git rid of `game1` and `game2` panels, they are adding nothing and causing you all the problems.

You will also find that if you override the `getPreferredSize` methods of `DrawingDemoPanel` and `SubKillerPanel` and return an appropriate size, that they will layout better.

Alternativly, you could create a single `game` panel and use a `GridLayout` to add the `DrawingDemoPanel` and `SubKillerPanel` to it, then add this to the `CENTER` position of the main window it will allow out better...